need help figuring out why i keep getting undefined method 'comments' in the ruby on rails blog tutorials
I'm trying out ruby on rails for a project and up to this point its been great but when following the tutorial and i get to 8, for comments, it just doesnt work? ive try to go back and reread, but i always get the undefined method with the comments being the part not working. the route is there so i dont know what is wrong as ive followed the tutorial perfectly (i think) for the comment part.

NoMethodError in Articles#show
Showing C:/blog/app/views/articles/show.html.erb where line #17 raised:

undefined method `comments' for an instance of Article


16 <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
17 <%= form_with model: [ @article, @article.comments.build ] do |form| %>
18 <p>
19  <%= form.label :commenter %><br>
20  <%= form.text_field :commenter %>

here are my codes, which for the most part follow the tutorial
articles/show
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>

<p><%= @article.body %></p>
<br>
<br>
<h3>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>  <br> 
<%= link_to "Destroy", article_path(@article), data: {
    turbo_method: :delete,
    turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?"
  } %>  <br>
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
</h3>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>
    <%= comment.commenter %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_with model: [ @article, @article.comments.build ] do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :body %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

comments_controller
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end

models/articles
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
  end
  

models/comments
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
end

schema
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.1].define(version: 2024_06_07_161059) do
  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "commenter"
    t.text "body"
    t.integer "article_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["article_id"], name: "index_comments_on_article_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "comments", "articles"
end

routes
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "articles#index"

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
end


here's a screenshot of the page when i try to access an article 
ive tried going back and copying everything again, ive trying modifying some part of the code, but im not currently really familiar with ruby so im not really sure where to look, and nothing i found online is excactly my problem

add your article model to the question

you need to add to the Article model has_many :comments

You missed the section 8:2 Associating Models.
